# How to use InAppBrowser in nativescript

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I added [Nativescript inAppBrowser plugin](https://www.nsplugins.com/plugin/nativescript-inappbrowser) to my nativescript core(javascript) project. i copied the code as it is in the documentation into my project, but it wasnt working (i'm guessing because its written in typescript) so i edited the code.

Now, i'm getting the error `InAppBrowser.isAvaialble` is not a function

this is my javascript code

```
const openUrl = require("tns-core-modules/utils/utils").openUrl;
const alert = require("tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs").alert;
const InAppBrowser = require("nativescript-inappbrowser");

videoCall: function (args) {
    try {
      const url = "https://example.com";
      if (InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
        const result = InAppBrowser.open(url, {
          // iOS Properties
          dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
          preferredBarTintColor: '#453AA4',
          preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
          readerMode: false,
          animated: true,
          modalPresentationStyle: 'fullScreen',
          modalTransitionStyle: 'partialCurl',
          modalEnabled: true,
          enableBarCollapsing: false,
          // Android Properties
          showTitle: true,
          toolbarColor: '#6200EE',
          secondaryToolbarColor: 'black',
          enableUrlBarHiding: true,
          enableDefaultShare: true,
          forceCloseOnRedirection: false,
          // Specify full animation resource identifier(package:anim/name)
          // or only resource name(in case of animation bundled with app).
          animations: {
            startEnter: 'slide_in_right',
            startExit: 'slide_out_left',
            endEnter: 'slide_in_left',
            endExit: 'slide_out_right'
          },
          headers: {
            'my-custom-header': 'MVM'
          }
        })
        alert({
          title: 'Response',
          message: JSON.stringify(result),
          okButtonText: 'Ok'
        })
      }
      else {
        openUrl(url);
      }
    }
    catch(error) {
      alert({
        title: 'Error',
        message: error.message,
        okButtonText: 'Ok'
      })
  }
},
```

You can compare it to the one in the documentation to see if there's anything i'm doing wrong, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to be `async` and you need to have `await` in front of all calls to InAppBrowser.

```
import { openUrl } from 'tns-core-modules/utils/utils';
import { alert } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs';
import InAppBrowser from 'nativescript-inappbrowser';

async function openLink(url) { 
    try {
        if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
            await InAppBrowser.open(url, {
                // iOS Properties
                dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
                preferredBarTintColor: '#453AA4',
                preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
                readerMode: false,
                animated: true,
                modalPresentationStyle: 'fullScreen',
                modalTransitionStyle: 'partialCurl',
                modalEnabled: true,
                enableBarCollapsing: false,
                // Android Properties
                showTitle: true,
                toolbarColor: '#6200EE',
                secondaryToolbarColor: 'black',
                enableUrlBarHiding: true,
                enableDefaultShare: true,
                forceCloseOnRedirection: false,
                // Specify full animation resource identifier(package:anim/name)
                // or only resource name(in case of animation bundled with app).
                animations: {
                    startEnter: 'slide_in_right',
                    startExit: 'slide_out_left',
                    endEnter: 'slide_in_left',
                    endExit: 'slide_out_right'
                },
                headers: {
                }
            });
        }
        else {
          openUrl(url);
        }
      }
      catch(error) {
        alert({
          title: 'Error',
          message: error.message,
          okButtonText: 'Ok'
        })
      }
```